# Tomcat error when starting StandardContext

Tags: spring, tomcat

When I run TomCat with a deployed web project on it. I started getting exceptions, which kills and restarts my project constantly.

There is stacktrace:

```
    Nov 30, 2015 9:58:05 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ThreadLocalRandom$1] (value [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ThreadLocalRandom$1@5c1e8d8a]) and a value of type [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ThreadLocalRandom] (value [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ThreadLocalRandom@28aae326]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Nov 30, 2015 9:58:05 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@4276669e]) and a value of type [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.Submitter] (value [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$Submitter@7f0dec04]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Nov 30, 2015 9:58:08 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
SEVERE: Exception starting Context with name []
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3746)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.backgroundProcess(StandardContext.java:5528)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1381)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1381)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1349)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: entry
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResource.getJarInputStreamWrapper(JarResource.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResource.getContent(AbstractArchiveResource.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResourceInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2611)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:938)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResourceAsStream(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1117)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateJavaClassCache(ContextConfig.java:2165)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateJavaClassCache(ContextConfig.java:2158)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2060)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2012)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1961)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1936)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1897)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1149)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5066)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 8 more

Nov 30, 2015 9:58:08 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [] is completed
```

Comment: Your `war` file seems to be broken. Try to create a new `war` artefact.

Comment: If you are using maven, do a maven clean && maven install . If on IDE, then you can do same with IDE.

Comment: Not sure how to say correctly, I deploy inside eclipse, not creating separate `war` file, but just added my project to tomcat server in eclipse and run it there.